# How can I output the AM/PM part of a string received in military time using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, time

Say I have a string like 13:00, which is 1:00PM, but only the first two characters (13). How can I output a string datatype of the PM part? Like

```
'13'.print_ampm()
=> PM
```

Comment: Convert to a number and see if it's at least 12? Doesn't seem to require a library, unless you're looking for a localized am/pm string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Time#strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime), which is for formatting times. The `%p` flag will get you an uppercase "AM" or "PM":

```
t = Time.now
# => 2016-10-14 22:37:03 -0400

t.strftime('%p')
=> "PM"
```

For just a string that's not a `Time` object, use:

```
require 'time'
Time.parse('10:30').strftime('%p')
# => "AM"
Time.parse('23:30').strftime('%p')
# => "PM"
```

If you want lowercase, use `%P` instead:

```
Time.parse('23:30').strftime('%P')
# => "pm"
```

Comment: For anyone using strftime, unless you memorized all the combinations, here's a good website/tool that I use to build the string reference: http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is to use the Time.parse method as defined here:
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse

Like this:

```
require 'time'
hour = '13'
puts Time.parse("#{hour}:00").strftime('%p')   # PM
```

Comment: Is `'time'` a gem?

Comment: Or is it native to Ruby?

Comment: Its part of the native library, but you might have to require it in your code, depending on the framework you way or may not be using.

Comment: @Forwarding Thanks for choosing my answer, but John Feminella's answer is much more complete and descriptive, you should choose his answer.